# Php file is not uploading to folder

Tags: php

I've a html upload form. It's working in my Localhost. But It's not working on live sever. It's insert the information to db but not uploading the file to folder called **"photos"**.

**Php code:**

```
$upload_path = "photos/";
$upload = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos (photo_cap, photo_name, photo, date) 
VALUES('$title','$filenameuniq', '$file', '$uploadate')");

        if($upload)
        {                       
            if(!empty($file))
            {
                if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_path . $filenameuniq))
                {
                echo '<pre>Your file was not uploaded please try again here are your debug informations:'.print_r($_FILES) .'</pre>';                   
                }                   
            }//// upload to folder  

            echo "<font color=green>Successfully Updated.</font>";
            header("Refresh:2; url=allphotos.php");
            exit(); 
        }
```

**Debug:**

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => Blue hills.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => 
C:\Windows\Temp\php95FB.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 28521 ) )

Your file was not uploaded please try again here are your debug informations:1
```

Why it's not uploading to **"photos"** folder ? On server how it's show  C:\Windows ?

Comment: Have you enough permission for file upload?

Comment: Check the path and permission

Comment: I didn't see that. what is the permission for upload a file ? is it only write, read ?

Comment: Why is your file is uploaded to C:\Windws\Temp? Shouldn't it be uploaded at C:\Users\UserName\...? Check if you have the rights to write into the directory.

Comment: @tftd I'm checking it..

Comment: @tftd permission is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with max file size

```
Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
```

change the value to some higher value in php.ini.safer way is to reduce restrict the max upload size to 2mb

Comment: file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_file_uploads = 20

Comment: check my uploaded file size in php.ini file.

Comment: change that to 3M since you are uploading a file of 2.8 mb size then restart Apache then try again

Answer (score 0):

Put validate for size, and type. then check it..